# Execution continues without promise resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm using the node library `level` to read all the data from a leveldb instance. I'm wrapping the readStream of the `level` library with a promise so that I can set the result to a variable. For some reason, the promise never resolves, and `this.chain` is just an unresolved promise.

```
const Ledger = require('./ledger')

class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.ledger = new Ledger()
    this.chain = this.ledger.getAllBlocks()
    console.log(this.chain) // logs Promise { <pending> }
  }
}

module.exports = Blockchain
```

---

```
const leveldb = require('level')

class Ledger {
  constructor() {
    // This will create or open the underlying LevelDB store.
    this.db = leveldb('./.ledger.dat')
  }

getAllBlocks() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let stream = this.db.createReadStream()
      let blocks = []

      stream.on('data', data => {
        blocks.push(data.value)
      })
      .on('end', () => res(blocks))
    })
    .then(blocks => blocks)
  }
}

module.exports = Ledger
```

**EDIT**
As per Benitos request, here's how im initializing Blockchain.js:

```
const Blockchain = require('./src/blockchain')

let itpChain = new Blockchain(5.0)

while(true) {
  itpChain.run()
}
```

Comment: `.then(blocks => blocks)` is a noop. It doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Every call to `then` creates a new Promise. In the case you have you're just saying create a new Promise that resolves to the same value as the previous Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems normal to me that your `console.log(this.chain)` shows a pending promise. It's the very nature of asynchronous code.

What does `this.chain.then(result => console.log(result))` tell you? It should give you the results of the operation.

**EDIT**

Can you show the code where you instantiate `Blockchain`?. I'd try this:

```
// Blockchain.js
const Ledger = require('./ledger')

class Blockchain {
  constructor() {
    this.ledger = new Ledger()
    this.chain = this.ledger.getAllBlocks()
  }
  getBlocks()
    return this.chain
  }
}

module.exports = Blockchain
```

And another file to use it:

```
// app.js
const Blockchain = require('./Blockchain')
const bc = new Blockchain()
bc.getBlocks().then(results => console.log(results))
```

Comment: I would normally say that its expected behaviour as well, but notice that i do `.then` on the promise right after declaring it. This should give me the results, but doesn't

Comment: No, though you put a `.then` inside `getAllBlocks`, you also should  put a `.then` after, in the code that calls it.

Comment: I don't think thats how promises work, they don't need multiple `.then`s. I did what you asked, just to see, and I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Just edited my answer... I think it would help us to see how you instantiate and use `Blockchain`. Ooops I just edited it again, had made a mistake :/.

Comment: Thanks. What does the `run()` method do? Thing is, you really have to chain a `.then` after `this.chain` somewhere, but I guess, not in the constructor (your promise still isn't resolved when the constructor ends, which is why I suggested creating another method which you'd call and chain a `.then` after)

Comment: I ended up rewriting it to load the blocks first and then run the chain, according to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped. I struggled quite a bit with promises at first too! [This article](http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/promises-in-wicked-detail/) is a good read on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

In your code this.chain is an unresolved promise. We need to wait for the value.

```
this.ledger = new Ledger()
this.ledger.getAllBlocks().then(result => {
  console.log(result); // this will have the value
});
```

Comment: I have called `.then` at the end of the `getAllBlocks()` method already. This should return my results, without me needing to call `.then` again on `this.chain`

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your `.then` method is doing literally nothing and should be removed.

Comment: A `.then` doesn't block, you can't use it in one place and then assume synchronous code will have waited for it to complete

Comment: Okay. I've done what you suggested and I'm continuing to have the exact same issue.